# Access Geometry Data in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to analyze geometry data on the server side, so I won't have access to the viewer. Is there a way to query geometry data from a translated Revit model?

Comment: if you are fine with analyzing OBJ, you could take advantage of Model Derivative API to translate the source model to SVF/SVF2, and second-translate the specific objects to OBJ. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/xtract-geometry-from-source-file/

Comment: if you want to analyze the geometry of source model directly and the source model formats are from AutoCAD/Revit/Inventor/3DsMax, you could make a plugin of them (use their API to get geometry data), and run the plugin on those cloud engines on Design Automation of Forge: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/